# Howto change <p></p> tags to <br> tags on pressing enter

Tags: froala

In [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) editor, pressing "enter" closes the `</p>` tag and opens a new one.

Is it possible to change the behavior to insert the `<br>` tag without closing `<p>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to change the enter option http://editor.froala.com/options#enter.

Comment: Looks like Froala v2 changed the paragraphy option to `enter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
e for event 
                if (e.which == 13) {

                    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');

                    return false;
                }
   it insert two br insteda of p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation, it works for me:

```
      <script>
  $(function() {
    $('div#froala-editor-p').froalaEditor();

    $('div#froala-editor-div').froalaEditor({
      enter: $.FroalaEditor.ENTER_DIV
    });

    $('div#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor({
      enter: $.FroalaEditor.ENTER_BR
    });
  });
</script>
```

The link is [enter link description here][Froala paragraph replacing with br or div tags]

Comment: [https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/enter?_ga=2.252062670.614490601.1500395142-1511608497.1500395142]